# Why is my authentication provider not reached?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a secured Spring app, in which I have configured the following:

```
public static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authenticationProvider(myCustomProvider)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

`myCustomProvider` is autowired into the adapter, and for the moment is just a "hello world" authentication provider.

When I send a request to an endpoint in my app, I get a 403 Forbidden response, and the response body simply says "access denied." When I add a breakpoint to the authentication provider, it isn't hit.

I can see that `org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor` is what's denying access, specifically a line in `AbstractSecurityInterceptor`:

```
this.accessDecisionManager.decide(authenticated, object, attributes);
```

There is a single AccessDecisionVoter, which corresponds to the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter expression *any request authenticated*, as outlined above, and which votes to deny the request.

Can someone clarify why the security interceptor isn't delegating to the authentication provider at all in order to determine whether the request should be granted? And can anyone point out to me how to fix this issue?

Comment: How do you login? I can't see any authentication type. Without logging in, you provider isn't called. That okay.

Comment: There is no login. A JWT is expected to be provided on the request, issued by an external system. I want to use the authentication provider to validate the JWT and populate credentials and authorities.

Comment: Show your JWT code. How do you extract the JWT token?